# Webmatrix 3 Insert query using parameter from list

Tags: razor, webmatrix

My basic question is how can I take the selected value in a list and use that value in a SQL INSERT Statement.
I have 2 tables- Contacts and Salutation. When a record is to be inserted, a Salutation(Mr, Mrs,Dr etc) is selected from a list.For ease I have included only the code dealing with this.
The code actually works as is, however , I feel my solution is suspect.
Here is the code:-

```
@{
    var Saln="";


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

   <Form  method="post" action="">
   <select name="Choice"> 

 @{      
    var db1 = Database.Open("Contact");
    var selectCommand1 = "SELECT ID, Saln FROM Salutation";
    var selectedData1 = db1.Query(selectCommand1);

    foreach(var row1 in selectedData1)
     {
        <option value="@row1.ID">@row1.Saln</option>
     }
   } 
    </select> 
  @{      
   if (Request["Choice"] != null)
   {
   var  Sal=Request["Choice"];
   var db = Database.Open("Contacts");
   var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Contacts (Saln) VALUES( "+Request["Choice"]+')';
    db.Execute(insertCommand,Saln );

   }  
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The variable Sal or @0 is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should follow a good tutorial on ASP.NET WebPages, like those at http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials.

Anyway, your code could be:

```
@{
    var Saln="";
    var db1 = Database.Open("Contact");
    var selectCommand1 = "SELECT ID, Saln FROM Salutation";
    var selectedData1 = db1.Query(selectCommand1);

    if(IsPost)
    {
        if (Request["Choice"] != null)
        {
            var db = Database.Open("Contacts");
            var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Contacts (Saln) VALUES(@0)";
            db.Execute(insertCommand, Request["Choice"]);
        }
    }            
} 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <Form  method="post" action="">
    <select name="Choice"> 
        @foreach(var row1 in selectedData1)
        {
            <option value="@row1.ID">@row1.Saln</option>
        }
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am working through a number of Tutorials + a couple of books.Thus far, I havent found an example along the lines of your suggestion. It is excellent and I am very pleased and thankful for your speedy and most helpful response. It has opened a few doors for me and maybe it will help others too. Kind regards Jim